# how to add object to empty list

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add object to list  using setInterval to auto add the object every 1second but the output returns null as first index
Here my code below, I don't know where am getting it wrong
;

```
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
    const winners = [
      {
      name:'john',
      price: '200'
       },
     {
    name:'Micheal',
    price: '230'
      }
    ]
    
    


useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
 setSeconds(second => (second >= winners?.length ?  0 : second + 1));
 }, 3000);
           
  if(list?.length >=0){
  const newList = list.concat(winners?.[`${seconds}`])
  setList(newList)
 }
 if(winners.length === list?.length){
 clearInterval(interval);
  }
   return () => clearInterval(interval)
 }, [seconds]);
```

**This is the output am getting   // output**

```
 list = [

null, 
    {
      name:'john',
      price: '200'
    },
     null,
     {
      name:'Micheal',
      price: '230'
      }
    ]
```

******but I want this****

```
list = [
{
  name:'john',
  price: '200'
},
{
  name:'Micheal',
  price: '230'
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read from your code, you could remove all `null` values from the `Array`, by applying a `filter` method on it.

Try this:

```
setList(newList.filter(item != null));
```